# What tools will allow JSON requests to be scripted and automated (like SOAP UI)?

Tags: json

Can someone suggest me a JSON client tool to test my system just like how we use SOAP UI to test web services?

Comment: How are you sending the JSON? Whats the backend language, PHP, ASP, C, etc? As your using SOAP I'm going to hazard a guess at PHP?

Comment: What sort of testing do you want to do?

Comment: I believe you can do this with SOAP UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a convenient way to make HTTP calls and then view their responses:

http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

No, it cannot be used for performance testing or automated testing of any sort as such. I used to use it as a quick way to visually inspect if my service (which happened to talk JSON but could actually have been anything else) is talking correctly.

Here is an example of how one uses it (It's linked to from the previous page):
http://www.flickr.com/photos/subwiz/2865055073/

Comment: I went thorough the link. Does it support JSON?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by support for JSON? The program lets you make HTTP calls of all sorts from a convenient GUI. It doesn't care if you POST JSON content or something else. It also shows you the response (and if that response is JSON, then it will show that). i.e. It's a convenient way to make calls to any HTTP service which you want to test manually. Whether RESTful or not, and whether JSON based or not.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox [RestClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/restclient/) addon will do this.

Answer (score 1):

did you consider/try fiddler ?
it's not open source, but it's free. It also comes bundled with a Firefox extension  that lets you monitor all http calls in realtime.

url : http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Restty](http://datasymphony.com.au/products/restty/) an Open Source tool under Apache 2.0 license. It's a template-based command line tool for accessing RESTful JSON-based Web Services. It can be used for automated testing too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the warm greeting. Can you give one example of the post with right disclaimer?

Comment: Not offhand, no; most promotional stuff tends not to last long as answers, and searching on the terms I'm thinking off just shows questions that involve those terms. But it shouldn't be hard to figure out how to do it. But also be sure you read that FAQ I linked to: self-promotional stuff tends to be frowned upon in general, especially when it is your only content. RE your edit: It being Open-Source actually has *nothing* to do with this, incidentally.

Comment: Ok. I think I get the idea. Thanks for your help.