# How to encode a JSON object before using it by borswe URL testing

Tags: json, url, tapestry

```
http://localhost/catalog/{"request": "catalog","user_id": "test@gmail.com","purchased": "2"}
```

here goes my request URL. I need to test my service with a sample URL typed in browser. But it seems that many of the JSON items do not accepted by the server side. if i enter plane text string server works fine. I tried to encode the URL using http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php, but still the errors are there.

May be this is a problem which belongs to tapestry. Else i would like to get some help.

following request works.

```
 http://localhost/catalog/helloworld
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tapestry performs its own encoding of parameters within urls, which there is no replica for on the client side.

see [org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.URLEncoderImpl.encode(String)](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/services/URLEncoderImpl.html)

the reason 'helloworld' works as expected is that there are no 'special characters' so the escaped value would equal 'helloworld' anyway.

So you will either need to encode your json via java using tapestry's `URLEncoder` or write a client side replica.

that is, if i understand your question properly.

**EDIT** i was bored so I wrote the client side replica:

```
/**
 * see org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.URLEncoderImpl.encode(String)
 * correct as at tapestry 5.3.5
 */
function tapestryUrlEncodeParameter(input)
{
    var safe = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            + "01234567890-_.:";

    if (input === null)
        return "$N";

    input = input.toString();

    if (input === "")
        return "$B";

    var output = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        var ch = input.charAt(i);

        if (ch === '$')
        {
            output += "$$";
            continue;
        }

        if (safe.indexOf(ch) != -1)
        {
            output += ch;
            continue;
        }

        var chHex = ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
        while (chHex.length < 4)
            chHex = "0" + chHex;
        output += "$" + chHex;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you have server side? Either way you will have to decode your encoded json string on the server side if you want to do it this way.

A better solution might be to use a testing tool of some kind. This could be as simple as a jquery $.get request in a webpage or perhaps you might want to think about a more versatile HTTP client as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399092/json-client-tool)